# Can i use both REPLACE and SET in a query?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to use both `REPLACE` and `SET` in my query. Is it posible, or do i need to make two diffrent querys? Maby should i use `BEGIN`?

This is my query, and i got this warning message:

`Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

**PHP**

```
$query = "REPLACE INTO TABLE(
                column1,
                column2)
         VALUES(
                :column1,
                :column2)
         SET 
                column3 = CONCAT(column3,':column3')";

$query_params = array(
                      ':column1' => $column1,
                      ':column2' => $column2,
                      ':column3' => $column3);
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't but if column3 is just a CONCAT of old data in column3 with new data then you could use a trigger.

```
SET NEW.column3 = CONCAT(OLD.column3, NEW.column3);
```

Comment: Yes. column3 in database should be CONCAT with column3 NEW DATA. Where can i read about "SET NEW"?

Comment: Here is a good starting point: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: What is your query now? If you have the trigger in place it should be just:

    REPLACE INTO TABLE (column1, column2, column3) VALUES(1, 2, 3);

Comment: `REPLACE INTO TABLE(c1,c2,c3)VALUES(:c1,:c2,:c3);SET NEW.c3 = CONCAT(old.c3, NEW.:c3);";`

Comment: Now, the query is working but it's only replacing values. not `CONCAT` c3?

Comment: If i remove "`;`" `after VALUES()` i got this error code: `Syntax error or access violation 'SET NEW.c3 = CONCAT(OLD.c3, NEW.'c3')' at line 29`

Comment: The ; is required. This trigger will also need to be set to trigger BEFORE UPDATE.

Just to be clear, this command need to be in a trigger. It isn't a statement you can just execute on its own.

Comment: SET NEW.c3 = CONCAT(OLD.c3, NEW.:c3);REPLACE INTO table... give me this: Unknown system variable 'c3'